# знаю,что ошибка в предпоследней строчке,но не могу найти в чём ошибка

Tags: javascript

```
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<script> 
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
 return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
} 
function getCard(){
var cards = ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A'];
return cards[getRandomInt(0, cards.length - 1)];
}
function getSum(arr){ { 
var sum = 0
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i]=='J'||arr[i]=='Q'||arr[i]=='K'){
        arr[i]=10;
    }else if (arr[i]=='A'){
        arr[i]=11;
    }else{
        arr[i]=parseInt(arr[i]);
    }
    sum = sum+arr[i];
}
return sum;
}
var dealer = [getCard()];
var player = [getCard(), getCard()];
alert('дилер: ' + dealer.join(' ') + ' игрок: ' + player.join(''));
alert('текущая сумма карт у игрока: ' + getSum(player));
</script>
```

Comment: Ошибка в предпоследней строчке

Answer (score 4):

Проблема в твоей невнимательности, лишняя фигурная скобка

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function getCard() {
  var cards = ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A'];
  return cards[getRandomInt(0, cards.length - 1)];
}

function getSum(arr) { // вот тут была лишняя { скобка
  
  var sum = 0
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == 'J' || arr[i] == 'Q' || arr[i] == 'K') {
      arr[i] = 10;
    } else if (arr[i] == 'A') {
      arr[i] = 11;
    } else {
      arr[i] = parseInt(arr[i]);
    }
    sum = sum + arr[i];
  }
  return sum;
  
}
var dealer = [getCard()];
var player = [getCard(), getCard()];
alert('дилер: ' + dealer.join(' ') + ' игрок: ' + player.join(''));
alert('текущая сумма карт у игрока: ' + getSum(player));
```